# How to deploy pulsarra.rar in Jboss?

Tags: jboss, jms, datastax, pulsar

I'm trying to deploy and configure DataStax Apache Pulsar JMS Client Resource Adapter in JBoss but I'm getting the following error:

```
2023-08-28 11:21:30,684 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment pulsarra.rar
2023-08-28 11:21:30,810 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] (MSC service thread 1-5) No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
2023-08-28 11:21:30,848 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
2023-08-28 11:21:30,991 INFO  [com.datastax.oss.pulsar.jms.rar.PulsarResourceAdapter] (MSC service thread 1-3) setConfiguration {"brokerServiceUrl":"pulsar://localhost:6650","webServiceUrl":"http://localhost:8080"}
2023-08-28 11:21:31,002 INFO  [com.datastax.oss.pulsar.jms.rar.PulsarResourceAdapter] (MSC service thread 1-3) startPulsarConnectionFactory {"brokerServiceUrl":"pulsar://localhost:6650","webServiceUrl":"http://localhost:8080"}
2023-08-28 11:21:31,079 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-4) MicroProfile: Metrics activated
2023-08-28 11:21:31,305 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) IJ020013: Connection factory not bound: com.datastax.oss.pulsar.jms.rar.PulsarManagedConnectionFactory
2023-08-28 11:21:31,306 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) IJ020015: Connection factory not specification compliant. See 6.5.1.3 for additional details: com.datastax.oss.pulsar.jms.PulsarConnectionFactory
2023-08-28 11:21:31,314 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ra.deployment."pulsarra.rar_PulsarRA": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ra.deployment."pulsarra.rar_PulsarRA": WFLYJCA0046: Failed to start RA deployment [pulsarra.rar]
    at org.jboss.as.connector@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService$2.run(AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:340)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: IJ020056: Deployment failed: file:/home/manuel/tools/jboss-eap-7.3/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp7ade9d00bcac3529/content-6b5e2cac829e1ded/contents/
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.19.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:2058)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService$WildFlyRaXmlDeployer.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService.java:190)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService.java:128)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.validator.ValidatorException: Severity: ERROR
Section: 17.5.1.1
Description: ConnectionFactory must implement javax.resource.Referenceable
Code: com.datastax.oss.pulsar.jms.PulsarConnectionFactory

    ... 11 more
```

My procedure is:

1-Deploy pulsarra.rar

[image]

2-Configure the Resource Adapter (Configuration -> Subsytems -> Resource Adapter -> Add Resource Adapter)

[image]

So far no errors.

3-Specify a Connection Definition (Resource Adapter -> PulsarRA -> Connection Definitions -> Add)

[image]

Now, when I restart JBoss I get the error shown.

JBoss is expecting a javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory but I'm passing a javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.

From the ra.xml:

```
 <connectionfactory-interface>javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory</connectionfactory-interface>
 <connectionfactory-impl-class>com.datastax.oss.pulsar.jms.PulsarConnectionFactory</connectionfactory-impl-class>
 <connection-interface>javax.jms.TopicConnection</connection-interface>
 <connection-impl-class>com.datastax.oss.pulsar.jms.PulsarConnection</connection-impl-class>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a [validation rule](https://github.com/ironjacamar/ironjacamar/blob/dd0b53760cfcef3b804f69a28e0fdb5a39b885c8/validator/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/jca/validator/rules/cf/CFReferenceable.java#L60)  of the Connection Factory [Validator](https://github.com/ironjacamar/ironjacamar/blob/dd0b53760cfcef3b804f69a28e0fdb5a39b885c8/validator/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/jca/validator/Validator.java#L60) of the [ironjacmar 1.4.19](https://github.com/ironjacamar/ironjacamar) jboss submodule (that implements [Java EE Connector Architecture 1.7](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/connector_architecture-1_7-mrel-spec/) ), mandates that the provided connection factory implements [Referenceable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/jconnector/api/javax/resource/Referenceable.html) (e.g. by implementing [javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/jconnector/api/javax/resource/cci/ConnectionFactory.html)).

Though, no class from the [pulsar-jms repo](https://github.com/datastax/pulsar-jms) seems to implement `javax.resource.Referencable` or use `javax.resource.cci.*` anywhere.

I think opening an issue/question to the [pulsar-jms issues section](https://github.com/datastax/pulsar-jms/issues)  regarding the above would be justifiable.

The title could be: "Connection factory not specification compliant. See 6.5.1.3 for additional details: `com.datastax.oss.pulsar.jms.PulsarConnectionFactory`"

You can note that the referenced section above (from the Jakarta Connectors 1.7) says the following:

> A connection factory implementation class must
> implement the interface javax.resource.Referenceable. Note that the
> javax.resource.Referenceable interface extends the
> javax.naming.Referenceable interface. Refer to section Section 20.6.3, “Scenario:
> Referenceable” on page 20-19 for details on the JNDI reference mechanism.

but the provided connection factory does not implement it, resulting in the exception that you have provided.

I guess they should provide some additional classes for supporting the Connector Architecture spec.